Pass variable between pages in Python not being excepted
I'm trying to have an input element that the user puts text into, then they click the "check the text button", and that runs a certain check on the text, and returns the text in the second input.
but I have an issue in passing the text back from the function that checks the text (that is on a different page from the widgets) back into the input.
(just to mention - I did not include anything that the code actually does or any of the other imports in the project - it was just too long and didnt seem like it was needed for the question)
These are the widgets on the "Gui" page that has the Tkinter elements on it:
(i'm importing a function from the "Translate" page)
from Treanslate import chck_specific_text

#input for received text from user:
text_input = tk.Entry(root, width=30)
    entered_text = text_input.get()
    entered_text.pack(pady=5)

    #input for converted text output
    converted_txt_input = tk.Entry(root)
    converted_txt_input.pack()

    #button to run the check text in the first input
    check_text_b = tk.Button(root, text="Check this text", 
    command=chck_specific_text(entered_text))
    check_text_b.pack()


I want to know if its correct to use chck_specific_text function on this page,
How I can pass the converted_txt_input from "Gui" to "Translate" page in order to pass back the returned answer in to the input.

These are the functions that are dealing with it:
(I tried to import like this but it didn't work)
from Gui import converted_txt_input


def chck_specific_text(entered_text):
    entered_text_v = entered_text
    do something
    replaced_text = entered_text_v

       return

pyperclip.copy(replaced_text)
        #print(pyperclip.paste())
        paste_translation_in_result_input(replaced_text)
        entered_text_v = "" 

def paste_translation_in_result_input(text):
    converted_txt_input.insert(0, text)

How do I write things correctly to be able to pass things from page to page? or is there something specific I should add to the code, or should I write the code in a different way? how can I do it?
if any other details about the code or project are needed, I can add them - this was what seemed necessary to me.

What do you mean by "different page"? Are you running this from a webserver framework like Flask? Use session variables to save variables between pages.

I mean I have a page for widgets (using Tkinter) a page for functions, and a main page - that starts the program, and I need to pass a variable between the Gui page and the Translate page - within the PyCharm pages - while writing the code, but I get an error like this: "ImportError: cannot import name 'converted_txt_input' from partially initialized module 'Gui' (most likely due to a circular import)"

There are many previous questions about that error, please do a search.
